# Read Mifare Classic 1K UID with Nexus 5

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I know, that NFC Chip of Nexus 5 isn't compatible to Mifare Classic. 
But i only try to read the UID. This worked on Nexus 4 but it looks like it doesn't work
on Nexus 5 anymore.

Did any one of you succeed in reading Mifare Classic UID with Nexus 5? Is there any trick?

Thanks in advance and best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested with a Nexus 5 + Android 4.4 + [NFC TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo) and getting the UID of a MIFARE Classic card works just like it does on the Nexus 4.

Comment: I have the same issue with the nexus 9. I can't read the UID (the nfc isn't detected with NFC TagInfo). Did you heard something like this already ?

Answer (score 3):

I can verify NFC TagInfo does indeed read the UID, but that's all it's capable of doing -- apparently MIFARE Classic aren't "Universal RFID" cards fully conformant to the final standard. Broadcom NFC chipsets apparently won't handle MIFARE Classic.

If you're buying NFC tags beware of any that claim over 512 bytes of storage, they're probably the NXP 1K classic and not compatible. Look for 'NTAG203' or 'Topaz512' ones.

Reference:

http://www.rfid-blog.com/?p=2247

Comment: In some cases it's not possible. For example, in Russia there is card "Troika" is a ticket to buses, subway, trams and other transport. More than 10 millions people has this card and it is Mifare Classic. Only some phones can read and change card ballance and new Samsung, Motorola, LG and other brands - not.